# Recursively provisioning ACL access over Azure Storage container : time consuming

Tags: azure, powershell, acl, azure-powershell

I have a ADLS Gen2 account deployed in Azure. We are populating data to different teams to transform. For the security reasons, We only providing ACLs permissions. Now as the data becoming huge in size, in case new team introduced, we are getting issue while providing access to container level.
Currently we are using Powershell. Its taking around 5+ hrs if data in container is 20GB+.

Is there any way to reduce the time? Any other language can we used or alternate solution ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your PowerShell script.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a single storage container and are granting access on a per item basis.

This is not sustainable as the number of items and the number of teams grows.

You need to group the data in a way that you can grant access to a team for a set of data.

Possible options:

- Create several storage accounts, grant access to teams on a storage account level
- Create containers within the storage account, place data in containers, grant access on container level.

Comment: Yes I am granting access on container level only. But see if I have 100 containers and 1 container has 20 GB data. for the new team I am provisioning SPN/AD group via ACL. The script execution taking longer